Integrating Object detection via Serial Communication on Raspberry pi Pico
I am currently working on a project that involves integrating object detection technology with a servo motor control system. The objective is to enhance the functionality of my setup by enabling the system to respond to specific objects—in this case, a bottle.
My intended workflow is as follows: once the object detection system identifies a bottle, it will send a command to a receiver (specifically, a Raspberry Pi Pico). Upon receiving this command, the servo motor is expected to rotate 120 degrees, rest for 5 seconds, and then return to its neutral position.
However, as I am relatively new to this field, I am seeking guidance to ensure that my approach is correct and that I am aligning my implementation with best practices in both object detection and motor control.
Any insights, suggestions, or resources you could provide to assist me in refining my project would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and support.

import time

# Servo setup

servo_bottle = PWM(Pin(15))  # Servo for bottle lid

servo_utensil = PWM(Pin(16))  # Servo for utensil lid

servo_bottle.freq(50)

servo_utensil.freq(50)

# UART setup (Serial communication)

uart = UART(0, 9600)  # UART port 0, Baud rate 9600

def open_lid(servo):

    servo.duty_u16(3000)  # Adjust this value for "open" position

    time.sleep(5)  # Keep the lid open for 5 seconds

    servo.duty_u16(7000)  # Adjust this value for "closed" position

while True:

    if uart.any():  # Check if data is available on the serial line

        command = uart.readline().decode().strip()  # Read and decode command

        print(f"Received command: {command}")  # Debugging output

        if command == "bottle":

            print("Opening bottle lid.")

            open_lid(servo_bottle)  # Open the bottle lid

        elif command == "utensil":

            print("Opening utensil lid.")

            open_lid(servo_utensil)  # Open the utensil lid```

Here is my code for sending a command via Serial Communication:

Check detected objects and send commands to Pico

if len(filtered_detections) > 0:
        for class_id in filtered_detections.class_id:
            if class_id in object_class_ids_bottle:
                print("Bottle detected.")
                pico_serial.write(b'bottle\n')  # Send 'bottle' command
                time.sleep(1)  # Short delay to avoid sending duplicate commands
            elif class_id in object_class_ids_utensils:
                print("Utensil detected.")
                pico_serial.write(b'utensil\n')  # Send 'utensil' command
                time.sleep(1)

